# Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory keras: can I clean the memory or do some garbage collector?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using keras on tensorflow and I have a callback `on_epoch_end` where I calculate some custom metrics. I just recently enabled the GPU for tensorflow and I get the `Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory` error after couple of epochs. I have tried to search for a solution but it was all about reducing the batch size or setting some GPU management flags, which I tried with no success, even with reducing the batch size from 50 to 1 still get the same error, however if I change my callback to be `on_train_end` I don't get that error anymore and the training runs fine. Can anyone tell me why and how that could be solved ? is there some way that I can clean the memory on the end of my `on_epoch_end` callback ?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out it was a CPU memory problem not a GPU. my `on_epoch_end` callback creates an instance of the custom callback class and this is never destroyed, thus the memory gets fully occupied after couple of epochs. Simple `gc.collect()` at the end of my `on_epoch_end` call solved the problem